# What is the best way to reuse a for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, functional-interface

I am currently working on a Matrix class that (will) allow you to perform operations on it. However, because I am using a 2D array to represent the matrix inside the class, I've often found myself using the following loop (to do something with all elements):

```
    for (int y = 0; y < this.matrix.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < this.matrix[0].length; x++) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

What is a good way to reuse this loop, yet have it perform a different piece of code inside the loop?

I've thought about the functional Interfaces, but haven't quite figured those out.

Comment: Should presumably be `this.matrix[y]` not `this.matrix[0]` but otherwise there is nothing wrong with this

Comment: A functional interface could solve this, but will most likely slow down the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this in a method

```
void iterateMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix[0].length; x++) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

you can define a functional interface for the "do something"

```
interface MatrixVisitor {
    void accept(int x, int y, int value);
}
```

It's a "functional interface" because it only contains one method; you can mark it with `@FunctionInterface`, but that's only a marker and not necessary.

You can use this via

```
void iterateMatrix(int[][] matrix, MatrixVisitor consumer) {
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix[0].length; x++) {
            consumer.accept(x, y, matrix[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

The effect of it being a functional interface is that you can "implement" it using a lambda, like

```
iterateMatrix(this.matrix, (x, y, value) -> System.out.printf("value at %d/%d: %d%n", x, y, value));
```

The question remains whether this is the "best way", it's a rather trivial loop so I don't know if reusing it is worth it.

Comment: X and Y don't seem that useful on their own. Presumably you care about the value at X,Y too.

Comment: @michael you're right, didn't really think about the actual semantics and assumed those were the values.

Comment: Don't be shy, point out why it's called MatrixVisitor. OP, this is a "Visitor" design pattern, a special kind of "Strategy" pattern. Check them out in Wikipedia to learn about their theoretical use. The point is, that you can switch out the visitor to change the semantics of the loop, while keeping traversal the same, ie. reusing the loops.

Comment: You should add `@FunctionalInterface` to `MatrixVisitor`. --- You should fix the potential issue in the question and use `matrix[y].length` instead of `matrix[0].length`, so the code works for jagged arrays too, even though that doesn't adhere to the "matrix" part of the names.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah for operational code I would have a `Matrix` class, but the main point of this answer was explaining what a functional interface is. I intentionally left out the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation to make explicit that it's not required.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu you know the visitor pattern? Just because something is called Visitor and has an accept method, this doesn't mean that this is an example of the visitor pattern. Perhaps give the wikipedia page a try first...

Comment: This already makes much more sense. But if I'd sometimes not need the value parameter (the third parameter), would I have to create a new functional interface with only two parameters (int x and int y)?

Comment: EDIT: Or can I add a second accept function in the interface? Or does it then lose its function as functional interface?

Comment: @ReefG For something to work as a lambda target (functional interface), it need to have a SAM - single abstract method. So no, unless it's a default method (one with a default implementation)

Comment: @ReefG You can't add a second method - then it wouldn't be a functional interface anymore, as you said. But you can just ignore the unused value in the lambda you create (eg `iterateMatrix((x,y,v) -> System.out.printf("visiting (%d, %d)%n", x, y)` which doesn't print the value).

Answer (score 0):

You say you are not familiar with functional interfaces, so here's an alternative approach using normal classes, which allows you to use Java's for-each loop.

I assumed your matrix values were doubles, but if they aren't then switch out the doubles for whatever type you're using.

```
static class MatrixElement {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final double value;

    // ctor, getters
}

static Iterable<MatrixElement> matrixIterable(double[][] matrix) {
    final List<MatrixElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix[y].length; x++) {              
            elements.add(new MatrixElement(x, y, matrix[x][y]));
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
double[][] matrix = {{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}};
for (MatrixElement element : matrixIterable(matrix)) {
    System.out.println("(" + element.getX() + ", " + element.getY() + ") " + element.getValue());
}
```

Prints

```
(0, 0) 1.1
(1, 0) 3.3
(0, 1) 2.2
(1, 1) 4.4
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely something I will play with!